# How to display grid line on top of highchart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

How to display the grid line on top of chart,

I'm having red color grid line in my chart, how to display the grid line on top of chart

I'm trying by setting index in css

code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

                yAxis: {
            gridLineColor: 'red'
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pewx4esm/1/

Helps much appreciated

Comment: if you set div styles as "border-top:1px solid red;" than you will get grid line on top of chart.

Comment: @Yash have you seen the fiddle link, am asking how to display the grid lines which already present in the chart should display over the chart

Comment: .@Pandiyan, your question quite confusing. i have seen your fiddle link. it looked fine. i didn't understand why do you want grid lines over the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

            yAxis: {
        gridLineColor: 'red',
                gridZIndex:90
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Go through
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/chart-types for help regarding any property of highcharts